# El form se deshabilita

Tags: html

En mi código los `<input>` y el botón *enviar* del formulario me quedan deshabilitados cuando reduzco el navegador a menos de `600px` que es uno de los *breakpoints* que establecí

Intenté varias cosas, pero nada me dio resultado

- Aumentar el `height` del `<input>`
- Cambiar en *CSS* el `display:flex`  a `display: block`
- Quitar los `<label>` de los `<input>`

¿Alguien puede echarle un vistazo a ver si saben qué sucede?

```css
@import url(//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/ed5050574c9de07c7d0a559f8c6a02a7?family=AR+BERKLEY);



*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#aclaracion{
    
    width: 30%;
    
    background: linear-gradient(25deg, rgba(80,129,53,1) 0%, rgba(140,201,48,1) 87%, rgba(255,245,245,1) 100%);

    color:white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 3% 2% 2% 2%;
    
    /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; */
    
}
#aclaracion h2{
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 3%;

}
aside{
    display: flex;
}
.croack{
    color: #508135;
    font-weight:600;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
footer{
    background-color:rgba(140,201,48,1);
    
    
    /* margin-top:3%; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1.5%;

}
footer>address{
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:white;
}
footer>div>a>img{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#formulario {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-image: url(../imagenes/fondo_formulario.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
#formulario button{
    background-color:  #508135;
    color: white;
    margin-top:  2%;
    font-size:1.5em;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:2% 4%;
  }
#formulario_foto{
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#formulario_foto img{
    width: 100%;
}
 #formulario form{ 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.02);
        
 }
 #formulario form>h1{
     color: #508135;
     font-size: 2em;
 }
#formulario form>input, #formulario form>textarea {
    width:80%;
}
#formulario form>label{
    font-size:1.5em;
    /* align-self: flex-start; */
}
.fumigaciones{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
    font-family: "AR BERKLEY";
 }
 #gracias{
     width: 30vw;
     color: #4e4c4c;
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
     height: 40vh;
     border-radius: 10px;
     padding:2%;
     font-size:1.5em;
     text-align: center;
     box-shadow: 5px 2px 5px #4e4c4c ;
     
 }

 #gracias span{
     display: block;
     font-size:1.75em;
     margin-bottom: 1.5%;
     color: #508135;
     font-weight: 500;
 }
 #gracias_contenedor{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../imagenes/fondo_formulario.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
    
 }
 #hamburguesa{
     font-size:1.5em;
     display: none;
 }
header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
   
    
    background: #F0F3F0;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #F0F3F0, #FFFFFF);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #F0F3F0, #FFFFFF);
background: linear-gradient(to left, #F0F3F0, #FFFFFF);




}

header> h1{ 
    /* color:transparent; */
    background-image: url(../imagenes/logo_rana.png) ;
    width:234px;
    height: 104px;
    
}
header>h1>a{
    color:transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}


header nav ul {
    display: flex;

}
header nav ul li {
    margin: 0 1rem;
    list-style: none;
    
}
header nav ul li a {
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:1.5rem;
  color:black;
    
}

#inicio{
    
    font-size:1em;
    color: #508135;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#inicio:hover{
    
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 600;
   
}
#inscripcion{
    width: 30%;
    
}
#inscripcion p{
    font-size:1.5em;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #999999;
}
#inscripcion p>span{
    font-weight: 900;
    display: block;
}

input, textarea{ 
    border-radius:10px;
}
img[src="imagenes/twitter.png"], img[src="imagenes/facebook.png"], img[src="imagenes/instagram2.png"]{
    width: 10%;
}
#justicia{
    background-image: url(../imagenes/justicia.jpg);
    width:200px;
    height: 299px;
    margin:auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#legales{
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}
#legales_info{
   
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
#legales h1{
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #508135;
    width:20%;
    color:white;
    font-size:2em;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-top:2%;
    
}
#maps{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
}

.padding{ 
    
    padding: 1% 1% 2% 1%;
    
   
}
#section1{
    min-width: calc(100vw- 4%);
    font-size: 2.5em;
}


#section1 picture>img{
    width: 100%;
   
}



#servicios article{
    width: 80vw;
    
    box-shadow:0px 4px 11px 0px     #999999;
    margin: 3% auto 3% auto;
    padding: 2%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    
}
#servicios article picture {
    width: 50%;
    
}
#servicios article picture img{
    width: 100%;
}

#servicios article>div{
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 50%;
}

#servicios article>div>h1{
    color:#508135;
    font-size:2.5em;

}
#servicios article>div>p{
    
    font-size:2em;
    margin-top:3%;
   
}

#social-media>span>a{
    
    color:white;
    font-size: 3em;
    
}

#quienes_somos{
    margin-top: 3% ;
    margin-bottom:3%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
#quienes_somos h1{
    text-align:center;
    background-color: rgba(140,201,48,1);
    color: white;
    width:30vw;
    margin:auto;
    
}
#quienes_somos picture{
   z-index:1; 
   width: 60vw;
   
}
#quienes_somos picture>img{
    width: 100%;
   
    
 }


#quienes_somos p{
    
    margin-top:-3%;
    column-count:2;
    column-gap:3%;
    column-rule: 5px solid  rgb(228, 224, 224);
    border:1px solid rgb(228, 224, 224);
    padding: 6% 3% 3% 3%;
    text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1091px){
    
    #servicios {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
    }

    #servicios article{
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 45vw;
        
        

    }
    #servicios article>div, #servicios article>picture{
        width: 100%;
    }

    #servicios article:first-child>picture, #servicios article:nth-child(3)>picture{
        order:0;
    }
    #servicios article:first-child>div, #servicios article:nth-child(3)>div{
        order:1;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:825px){
    aside{
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;

    }
    #formulario {
        width: 100%;
        order:1
    }

    #formulario_foto{
        width:100%;
        order:0;
        
    }
    
}

@media screen and (max-width:774px){
    #servicios {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        
    }

    #servicios article{
        width:90vw;
    }
    #legales_info{
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items:center;
    }
    #inscripcion{
        width:60%;
    }
    #aclaracion{
        margin-top:3%;
        width:60%;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width:600px){
    #aclaracion{
        width: 90%;
    }
    footer>address{
        text-align: center;
    }


    header h1{
        background-image: url(../imagenes/logo_rana_reducido.png) ;
        width:230px;
        height: 67px;
    }
    
    

    #justicia{
        display: none;
    }
    #legales h1{
        margin-bottom: 1%;
        
    }
    #quienes_somos h1, #legales h1{
        width:90vw;
    }
    #quienes_somos> p{
        column-count: 1;
        border:none;
    }

    #quienes_somos picture{
       display: none;
        
   

    
    }

    footer{
       
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }

   
    /* Menú hamburguesa*/
    #hamburguesa{
        display: block;
        order:1;
       
    }
    #hamburguesa li{
        line-height: 80px;
        
    }
    
    #botones{
        background-color:rgb(140,201,48);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    
    #botones li>a{
        color:white;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        font-size:2em;
        padding: 1em 0; 
        

    }
    header{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 80px;
    }
    header> h1{
        
        height: 100%;
        margin:auto;
        
    }
    header>h1>a{
        display: block;
    }

    header> nav{
       
        position: absolute;  
        top: 0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height: 100vh;
         
        
    }
  
    header>nav>ul{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        
    }

    nav:target #botones{ display: block; }
     #botones{ display: none; } 
    
     #hamburguesa li:last-child { display: none; }
    nav:target #hamburguesa li:first-child{ display: none; }
    nav:target #hamburguesa li:last-child{ display: block; }

}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Contacto</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <header class="padding">
        <h1>
            <a href="index.html"> Fumigaciones</a> 
        </h1>
       
        <nav id="barra">
            <ul id="hamburguesa">
                <li><a href="#barra"> <i  class="fas fa-bars"></i> </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">   <i  class="fas fa-bars"></i> </a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="botones">
                
                <li> <a href="servicios.html" target="_blank"> Servicios</a>  </li>
                <li> <a href="legales.html" target="_blank">Legales</a></li>
                <li> <a href="contacto.html" target="_blank"> Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
           
            
        </nav>

        
    </header>

    <aside>
        
        <div id="formulario">
            
            <form action="gracias.html">
                <h1>Contáctenos</h1>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre y Apellido</label>
                <input type="text" id="nombre">
                <label for="correo">Correo Electrónico</label>
                <input type="email" id="correo">
                <label for="consulta">Envíe su consulta</label>
                <textarea name="consulta" id="consulta" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

                <button>Enviar</button>

            </form>
        </div>
            
        <picture id="formulario_foto">
            <img src="imagenes/control_de_plagas_ajustada.jpg" alt="fumigacion">
        </picture>
    </aside>

    <iframe id="maps" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3284.0041936355615!2d-58.39817038519524!3d-34.60405546502211!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x95bccaea5df5d30b%3A0xc697ad49a94641ca!2sAv.%20Corrientes%202037%2C%20C1045%20AAC%2C%20Buenos%20Aires!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sar!4v1613397132814!5m2!1ses!2sar"    style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>

    <footer>
        <address>
            <p> Av Corrientes 1080</p> 
            <p> 5134-5768</p> 
        </address>
        <div id="social-media">
            <span>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i></a> 
            </span>

            <span>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a> 
            </span>

            <span>
               <a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a> 
            </span>

            
            
        </div>

        
    </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es debido a que en el media screen de <600px tienes puesto que header> nav sea con un height del 100%, por lo que se te queda por encima y estas haciendo click a la navbar en vez del formulario. Te adjunto el css rectificado!

Espero haberte ayudado

```css
@import url(//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/ed5050574c9de07c7d0a559f8c6a02a7?family=AR+BERKLEY);



*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#aclaracion{
    
    width: 30%;
    
    background: linear-gradient(25deg, rgba(80,129,53,1) 0%, rgba(140,201,48,1) 87%, rgba(255,245,245,1) 100%);

    color:white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 3% 2% 2% 2%;
    
    /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; */
    
}
#aclaracion h2{
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 3%;

}
aside{
    display: flex;
}
.croack{
    color: #508135;
    font-weight:600;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
footer{
    background-color:rgba(140,201,48,1);
    
    
    /* margin-top:3%; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1.5%;

}
footer>address{
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:white;
}
footer>div>a>img{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#formulario {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-image: url(../imagenes/fondo_formulario.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
#formulario button{
    background-color:  #508135;
    color: white;
    margin-top:  2%;
    font-size:1.5em;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:2% 4%;
  }
#formulario_foto{
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#formulario_foto img{
    width: 100%;
}
 #formulario form{ 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.02);
        
 }
 #formulario form>h1{
     color: #508135;
     font-size: 2em;
 }
#formulario form>input, #formulario form>textarea {
    width:80%;
}
#formulario form>label{
    font-size:1.5em;
    /* align-self: flex-start; */
}
.fumigaciones{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
    font-family: "AR BERKLEY";
 }
 #gracias{
     width: 30vw;
     color: #4e4c4c;
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
     height: 40vh;
     border-radius: 10px;
     padding:2%;
     font-size:1.5em;
     text-align: center;
     box-shadow: 5px 2px 5px #4e4c4c ;
     
 }

 #gracias span{
     display: block;
     font-size:1.75em;
     margin-bottom: 1.5%;
     color: #508135;
     font-weight: 500;
 }
 #gracias_contenedor{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../imagenes/fondo_formulario.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
    
 }
 #hamburguesa{
     font-size:1.5em;
     display: none;
 }
header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
   
    
    background: #F0F3F0;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #F0F3F0, #FFFFFF);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #F0F3F0, #FFFFFF);
background: linear-gradient(to left, #F0F3F0, #FFFFFF);




}

header> h1{ 
    /* color:transparent; */
    background-image: url(../imagenes/logo_rana.png) ;
    width:234px;
    height: 104px;
    
}
header>h1>a{
    color:transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}


header nav ul {
    display: flex;

}
header nav ul li {
    margin: 0 1rem;
    list-style: none;
    
}
header nav ul li a {
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:1.5rem;
  color:black;
    
}

#inicio{
    
    font-size:1em;
    color: #508135;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#inicio:hover{
    
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 600;
   
}
#inscripcion{
    width: 30%;
    
}
#inscripcion p{
    font-size:1.5em;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #999999;
}
#inscripcion p>span{
    font-weight: 900;
    display: block;
}

input, textarea{ 
    border-radius:10px;
}
img[src="imagenes/twitter.png"], img[src="imagenes/facebook.png"], img[src="imagenes/instagram2.png"]{
    width: 10%;
}
#justicia{
    background-image: url(../imagenes/justicia.jpg);
    width:200px;
    height: 299px;
    margin:auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#legales{
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}
#legales_info{
   
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
#legales h1{
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #508135;
    width:20%;
    color:white;
    font-size:2em;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-top:2%;
    
}
#maps{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
}

.padding{ 
    
    padding: 1% 1% 2% 1%;
    
   
}
#section1{
    min-width: calc(100vw- 4%);
    font-size: 2.5em;
}


#section1 picture>img{
    width: 100%;
   
}



#servicios article{
    width: 80vw;
    
    box-shadow:0px 4px 11px 0px     #999999;
    margin: 3% auto 3% auto;
    padding: 2%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    
}
#servicios article picture {
    width: 50%;
    
}
#servicios article picture img{
    width: 100%;
}

#servicios article>div{
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 50%;
}

#servicios article>div>h1{
    color:#508135;
    font-size:2.5em;

}
#servicios article>div>p{
    
    font-size:2em;
    margin-top:3%;
   
}

#social-media>span>a{
    
    color:white;
    font-size: 3em;
    
}

#quienes_somos{
    margin-top: 3% ;
    margin-bottom:3%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
#quienes_somos h1{
    text-align:center;
    background-color: rgba(140,201,48,1);
    color: white;
    width:30vw;
    margin:auto;
    
}
#quienes_somos picture{
   z-index:1; 
   width: 60vw;
   
}
#quienes_somos picture>img{
    width: 100%;
   
    
 }


#quienes_somos p{
    
    margin-top:-3%;
    column-count:2;
    column-gap:3%;
    column-rule: 5px solid  rgb(228, 224, 224);
    border:1px solid rgb(228, 224, 224);
    padding: 6% 3% 3% 3%;
    text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1091px){
    
    #servicios {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
    }

    #servicios article{
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 45vw;
        
        

    }
    #servicios article>div, #servicios article>picture{
        width: 100%;
    }

    #servicios article:first-child>picture, #servicios article:nth-child(3)>picture{
        order:0;
    }
    #servicios article:first-child>div, #servicios article:nth-child(3)>div{
        order:1;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:825px){
    aside{
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;

    }
    #formulario {
        width: 100%;
        order:1
    }

    #formulario_foto{
        width:100%;
        order:0;
        
    }
    
}

@media screen and (max-width:774px){
    #servicios {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        
    }

    #servicios article{
        width:90vw;
    }
    #legales_info{
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items:center;
    }
    #inscripcion{
        width:60%;
    }
    #aclaracion{
        margin-top:3%;
        width:60%;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width:600px){
    #aclaracion{
        width: 90%;
    }
    footer>address{
        text-align: center;
    }


    header h1{
        background-image: url(../imagenes/logo_rana_reducido.png) ;
        width:230px;
        height: 67px;
    }
    
    

    #justicia{
        display: none;
    }
    #legales h1{
        margin-bottom: 1%;
        
    }
    #quienes_somos h1, #legales h1{
        width:90vw;
    }
    #quienes_somos> p{
        column-count: 1;
        border:none;
    }

    #quienes_somos picture{
       display: none;
        
   

    
    }

    footer{
       
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }

   
    /* Menú hamburguesa*/
    #hamburguesa{
        display: block;
        order:1;
       
    }
    #hamburguesa li{
        line-height: 80px;
        
    }
    
    #botones{
        background-color:rgb(140,201,48);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    
    #botones li>a{
        color:white;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        font-size:2em;
        padding: 1em 0; 
        

    }
    header{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 80px;
    }
    header> h1{
        
        height: 100%;
        margin:auto;
        
    }
    header>h1>a{
        display: block;
    }

    header> nav{
       
        position: absolute;  
        top: 0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
         
        
    }
  
    header>nav>ul{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        
    }

    nav:target #botones{ display: block; }
     #botones{ display: none; } 
    
     #hamburguesa li:last-child { display: none; }
    nav:target #hamburguesa li:first-child{ display: none; }
    nav:target #hamburguesa li:last-child{ display: block; }

}
```